# Ordering data in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have table like this:

```
"users":{
      "$userUID":{
        "dm":{
            "$roomID":{
                "date":1617755185,
                "lastmessage":"Hi"
            }
        }
      }
}
```

And I want to query rooms($roomID) ordering them by date
So code is:

```
val reference:DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!).child("dm")
var query:Query = reference.orderByChild("date").startAt($previousRoomId).limitToLast(2)
```

But there is no data and message:
`Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "date"' at users/fDX9PVJpQxXCVoQzOUS7USarVcv2/dm`

I have tried to add `"users":{".indexOn":"date }` in my firebase rules but it didnt help. What sould I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define that index on the path where the query runs.

By adding `"users":{".indexOn":"date" }` you've defined an index that allows you to run a query on `/users` and that then contains the value of `date` for each direct child node. That might be useful in some cases, but it is not the index that the code you shared needs.

Since that code queries `/users/$uid/dm` you need to define the index at that path:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "dm": {
          ".indexOn": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$uid` [wildcard variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables) in the above means that the rules under it apply to each child node of `users`, so each user's `dm` node gets its own index.